# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'write' error while writing into a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler      
from textfsm import * 

cisco_device = { 'device_type' : 'cisco_ios', 'ip' : 'x.x.x.x', 'username':'gtomy200', 'password':'xxxxx'}
net_connect = ConnectHandler(**cisco_device)

fo=("testme.txt" , 'w')

output = net_connect.send_command("show int brief")

re_table = TextFSM(open('xr_show_int_br','r'))    

data = re_table.ParseText(output)

print (output)

for s in re_table.header:

          fo.write("%s;" %s)

fo.write("\n")

for row in data:
        print (row)
        for s in row:

                fo.write("%s" %s)
                fo.write("\n")

fo.close()
```

can someone help out, regarding the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gtomy200/Desktop/Py/test.py", line 20, in 
    fo.write("%s;" %s)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to ensure you `open` the file:

```
fo = open("testme.txt" , 'w')
#    ^^^^
```

As it is you were trying to write to a two-tuple:

```
fo = ("testme.txt", 'w')
#    ^ no open
```

which won't work.

Answer (score 0):

`fo` is a **tuple**, use `with open()` for file operations. It's safier and easier.

```
with open ("myfile.txt","w") as ff:
    ff.write("string") #you can't use anything but strings in here, 
                       #so convert your variables to string
```